# MySQL database performance issue. (MyISAM)

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

Im having online online auction website running live since near about 3 years and still going good.
Within 3 years so many auctions has been listed on server and completed too. but now there are a lot of load
on server as there are so many completed and live auction on database server. Therefore performance of website
is not what it was earlier. What should I do to improve the performance ?
All table are created using storage engine "MyISAM".

Comment: This depends on a large number of factors.  How about archiving a big chunk of the completed auction data so your live DB is smaller?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I didn't fully understand what you exactly mean by archiving and how to do it? I never come through such situation. Can you please explain in details how to perform archiving ? Can such data will be accessible with same php code later on or I will have to make some changes ?

Comment: Say your table is called `Auctions`.  You can create a table called `AuctionsBackup`.  DELETE all rows from `Auctions` that are complete and/or before some date (say 6 months ago) and put them in `AuctionsBackup` just so you don't lose them.  You can do this with php of course

Comment: Probably more likely an index issues than anything else..

Comment: Or you can convert your engine to InnoDB and backup your data to MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/17/using-myisam-in-production/) frist

- Basic & the frist thing you can do is index the tables.
- You will have to switch [MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb). [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)
- You can Backup the existing data and start from the beginning if possible

[Read More](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/)